# WordPress: Why shortcodes show a white page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have this code to show news in block. but when include this code in `function.php` to call it in shortcode. It show me white page and not show me any error.

Sow where is error.??

For some reason, when I edit my functions.php, various pages turn white. For exmaple, with this code:

```
function box_news_eight( $atts ) {
$code = '<div class="cf"></div>
<div class="box-home box-news-seven nb-eight">
    <div class="box-inner">
        <div  class="box-wrap">';
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 4, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'cache_results' => false ) );
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                if ( $i_cont == 0 ) { $post_class = ' ws-post-first'; } else { $post_class = ' ws-post-sec'; }
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { $has_class =  ''; } else { $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; }
               $code .= ' <div class="post'.$post_class.','. $has_class.'" role="article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">';              
                    $post_sidebars = '';
                    if ( $post_sidebars == 'sideNo' ) {
                        if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
                            $code .= ' <div class="ws-thumbnail"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">
                                    .'get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-normal' ).'
                                </a></div>';
                            endif;
                        } else {
                                if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                            $code .= '<div class="ws-thumbnail"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">';
                                        get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-large' );
                               $code .= '</a></div>';
                            endif; 
                        }
                    $code .= '<div class="ws-cap">
                        <div class="post-cats-bd">';
                            get_the_category( ' ' );
                        $code .= '</div>
                        <div class="ws-cap-inner">
                            <h3 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><a itemprop="url" href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title()'.</a></h3>
                            <div class="post-date-bd">'.
                                get_time().'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
                 $i_cont++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query();
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'offset'=>1, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'cat' => 4, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'cache_results' => false ) );
            update_post_thumbnail_cache( $query );
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                if ( $i_cont == 0 ) { $post_class = ' ws-post-first'; } else { $post_class = ' ws-post-sec'; }
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { $has_class =  ''; } else { $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; }
                if( $count % 3 == 1 ) { echo '<div class="row">'; }
                    $code .= '<div class="post'.$post_class, $has_class.'" role="article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                        <div class="ws-meta">
                            <h3 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><a itemprop="url" href="<'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).' rel="bookmark">'.the_title().'</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                      if( $count % 3 == 0 ) { echo "</div>\n"; }
                      $count++;

                      $i_cont++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query();
                  if ( $count % 3 != 1 ) echo "</div>";
        $code .= '</div>
    </div>
</div>';
return $code;
}
add_shortcode( 'box_news_eight', 'box_news_eight' );
```

Comment: `get_the_category( ' ' );` should just be `get_the_category();` if you are trying to get the current category. this function only takes one argument which should be an integer, currently you are passing in an empty string

Answer (score 2):

frist error

```
.'get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-normal' )
```

change to

```
'.get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-normal' )
```

second

```
get_the_title()'.
```

to

```
get_the_title().'
```

third

```
$post_class, $has_class
```

to

```
$post_class.$has_class
```

Comment: well there were 3 code errors, another problem can be that you are calling functions, that doesn't exists, try to comment line by line and see results

Comment: $code .= '<div class="post'.$post_class, $has_class.'"